# Approach clearance within a TAA

Tags: clearance

In a TAA with NOPT, control issues an approach clearance with an altitude restriction above the minimum altitude for the TAA. Control did not state straight-in, therefore are you required to preform the course reversal prior to executing the approach.

Comment: I am confused by what you mean by "control issues an approach clearance with an altitude restriction above the minimum altitude for the TAA." What was the exact wording used?

Comment: Did this happen to you?  What airport/approach?  Did you query ATC and ask for vectors for descent, or is this a hypothetical “what if”?  (And I don’t oppose what-if scenarios if they are plausible and learning can come from it…)

Answer (score 1):

If a procedure entry is marked "NoPT" you should not perform the procedure turn. If it is not marked "NoPT" you should perform an appropriate course reversal.<sup>1</sup> As far as I am aware, the vast majority of the time a procedure with a TAA will be marked "NoPT."

You will be cleared direct to either the left base, straight-in, or right base fix, and should perform a straight-in approach beginning at that fix. But see 5–4–5**d**7 for examples of modified TAAs which do not have one or both of the base areas; depending on the arrival course, a course reversal may be necessary.

---

I am confused about what you mean by "control issues an approach clearance with an altitude restriction above the minimum altitude for the TAA." It is possible that the minimum vectoring altitude is higher than the TAA minimum altitude, in which case—only if you are not already within the TAA—ATC should issue an instruction that sounds like:

> Cleared direct CHARR, maintain at or above five thousand **until entering the TAA**, cleared RNAV Runway One-Eight Approach.<sup>2</sup>

But an approach clearance is an authorization to descend according to the published approach procedure all the way down to the DA/DH, so they should not be issuing a blanket altitude clearance in conjunction with an approach clearance.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>[AIM 5–4–5**d**4](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_4.html#aim0504.html.11)</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>[7110.65 4–8–1**j**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap4_section_8.html#atc0408.html.6)</sup>